# MS Project 2010 Auto-calculating and setting Resource % Allocations

Tags: ms-project

been thinking about how to do this, maybe it requires a macro?

Scenario:

Resource A is allocated to Task 1 @ 50%, and Task 2 @ 50% for the same week. I now want to change the Task A allocation to 80%, which updates Work to 32hours, and want Task 2 to auto-update to 20% (and the respective Work to 8). Is this doable? Using leveling doesn't reallocate percentage but instead lengthens tasks.

Also appreciate that a particular difficulty is if Resource A is allocated to more than 2 tasks e.g. Task 1 @ 30%, Task 2 @ 30% and Task 3 @ 40%: if I update one, how does it take percent allocation from the other two?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method for Project to automatically change assignment units.  The overallocation alert is there to tell you when a resource is overallocated, but it is up to the project manager/scheduler to decide how to resolve the overallocation.